# Why Can't the Terra Novans Use Balloons with Infrared Cameras to Find the Sixers?

Tags: tv, terra-nova

In the 3rd episode of *Terra Nova* (counting the 2 hour pilot as 2 episodes), *Instinct*, they used infrared cameras on balloons to see how many of the pterosaurs were in the area.  Why can't they just start floating more balloons and use them to scan for humans to find where the Sixers are encamped?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the plot doesn't want it to happen (yet?).

I see 2 possible reasons:

1. It only worked with the pterosaurs because they were above the
   canopy, and the 6ers knew how to hide.
2. It only worked with the pterosaurs because there were so many, and
   their heat bled through the canopy to make the signature visible.

In the 4th episode (by your same count), the heat signature from the human was blocked by the nearby plants, so it took them a bit of time to see the person.

Comment: This.  IR is hard to see if it's moving, and especially if it's under cover and from small sources.  If you're aware enough to try to hide your IR signature and have any significant resources or time, it's almost trivial.